# Proving that $(2^3)^{\log_2 n}=n^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

may someone help me understand why $$\large (2^3)^{\log_2 n}=n^3$$

I don't know if this helps but we know that:
$$\large 2^{\log_2 n}=n$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}=(a^c)^b$, so
$$
(2^3)^{\log_2 n}=(2^{\log_2 n})^3=n^3.
$$

Comment: But what if I have $a^{b^c}$, can I use what u wrote above?

Comment: No, you can't. When we write $ {a^b}^c $ what we mean is $ {a}^{({b^c})} $, as opposed to $(a^b)^c$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $(x^a)^b = x^{ab} = (x^b)^a$.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simple:
$$\bigl(2^3\bigr)^{\log_2 n}=\bigl(2^{\log_2n}\bigr)^3=n^3.$$

Answer (score 2):

I would like to mention a formula here that is pretty useful:
$$a^{\log_bc}=c^{\log_ba}$$
Notice that I've simply switched $a$ and $c$. Proving this is straightforward. I'll leave it to you for practice. If you need a hint, you can ask in the comments.

Coming to the use of this formula in the question, Let's pick up from where you left off:
$$2^{\log_2n}=n^{\log_22}=n^1=n \;\;\; .$$

Answer (score 1):

$$(2^3)^{\log_2n}=(2)^{3\log_2n}=(2)^{\log_2(n^3)}=n^3$$